# breakable box with varwidth

Tags: boxes, paragraphs, mdframed, fbox, varwidth

**PROBLEM**

Build an environment to put some text in some boxes that should be both breakable across a page *and* adapt to text width. Unfortunately, packages `mdframed` and `tcolorboxes` have the first option, but not the second, because it seems that `varwidth` makes them uncomfortable.

**PROPOSED SOLUTION**

Build two environments.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
\documentclass{article}
    % General document formatting
    \usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    % Related to math
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}

    % just for this example
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    % lists
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\ast$}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{--}

    % colors
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,32,155}
    \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{192,0,0}
    \definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{68,84,106}
    \definecolor{myred2}{RGB}{180,4,38}
    \definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{238,132,104}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{26,152,80}

    % url
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    % useful comments
    \usepackage{varwidth}
    \usepackage{mdframed}

    \mdfdefinestyle{basemdstyle}{%
        skipabove=1em,
        skipbelow=1em,
        innertopmargin=0.75em,
        innerbottommargin=0.75em
        }
        \newmdenv[style=basemdstyle]{baseemph}

    % breakable 
    \newcommand\lredemph[1]{%
            \begin{baseemph}[fontcolor=myred]%
                {#1}%
            \end{baseemph}}

    % width-adaptive
    \newcommand\redemph[1]{\fbox{%
            \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}%
                {\textcolor{myred}{#1}}%
            \end{varwidth}%
        }\par}


\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\lredemph{\textbf{this will go across pages.} \Blindtext}

\redemph{this will be just as large as the text}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

comments added inline

```
\documentclass{article}
    % General document formatting
    \usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
% avoid utf8x use utf8 on old latex releases,   use nothing on current releases \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
% not needed in current releases textcomp
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    % Related to math
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}

    % just for this example (not very Italian:-)
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    % lists
    \usepackage{enumerate} % I wrote this, but enumitem is better
    \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\ast$}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{--}

    % colors
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,32,155}
    \definecolor{myred}{RGB}{192,0,0}
    \definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{68,84,106}
    \definecolor{myred2}{RGB}{180,4,38}
    \definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{238,132,104}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{26,152,80}

    % url
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    % useful comments
    \usepackage{mdframed}

    \mdfdefinestyle{basemdstyle}{%
        skipabove=1em,
        skipbelow=1em,
        innertopmargin=0.75em,
        innerbottommargin=0.75em
        }
        \newmdenv[style=basemdstyle]{baseemph}

    % breakable 
%if the text takes multiple lines use mdframed otherwise fbox
    \newcommand\lredemph[1]{%
\setbox0\vbox{{#1\par}}%
\ifdim\ht0>\baselineskip
            \begin{baseemph}[fontcolor=myred]%
                #1%
            \end{baseemph}%
\else
   \fbox{\textcolor{myred}{#1}}%
\fi}



\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\lredemph{\textbf{this will go across pages.} \Blindtext}

\lredemph{this will be just as large as the text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's something I was looking for and makes the use of the ```newcommand``` way easier.